# Sign In With Apple Using Firebase on Web and Mobile Apps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, sign-in-with-apple

I'm currently having trouble getting Sign In With Apple to work on my mobile app and my web app at the same time.

I'm using React Native/Expo for my mobile app and ReactJS for my web app.

Authentication works fine on web when I use the Services ID from Apple and input it in the Services ID on Firebase. Authentication works fine on mobile when I use the App ID from Apple and input it the Services ID on Firebase.

Since the App ID and Services ID must be unique on Apple and there is only 1 place to input them on Firebase, I can't have them working at the same time. When I use an identifier for one platform, I would get an error on the other and vice versa.

Does anyone know a solution or workaround for this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you manage to find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add your iOS app to the Firebase :  "Project Overview" -> "Project settings" -> General -> "Add app".
2. Use the Service Id of your website from Apple in the Apple Sign in configuration for the Firebase.

It should work now for both your mobile app and the website.

Comment: Adding the "iOS app" to the Firebase project does indeed fix it - I had the same problem as OP, where I could not use the bundle ID as the Service ID but if I used a different service ID I got an error from the iOS app React Native app "The audience in ID Token [my bundle id] does not match the expected audience [my service id]". As soon as I did your Step 1, this magically fixed itself - without having to do anything further.